# Copying a list in python

Tags: python, list, copy

I'm looking for a way to do the following:

- I have a list composed of other lists:`TABLE=[table1,table2,table3]`
- I would like to duplicate this list but rename the sublists, such as:`TABLE_1=[table1_dup=list(table1),table2_dup=list(table2),table3_dup=list(table3)]` (this doesn't work; I'm just trying to explain my goal) so that I can access tablex and tablex_dup independently after performing batch operations on the whole TABLE and TABLE_1, which include table1, table2,  ... and the duplicates.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: The sublists aren't necessarily named the same (table1, table2, table3). Actually, their names are quite different (e.g. up, down, left, right)

EDIT #2:
I'm kinda new to this. Basically, here's my code:

```
up=["img1.png","img2.png"]
```

similar things for down, left and right.

```
table=[up,down,left,right]
```

Now using pygame:

```
for j in range(len(table)):
        for i in range(len(table[j])):
            table[j][i] = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(str(table[j][i])))
            table_r[j][i] = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(str(table_r[j][i])))
            table_r[j][i] = pygame.transform.flip(table_r[j][i],1,0)
```

This wouldn't work as there is no up_r, for example, that I could access. Only up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the more general issues raised in the comments and by your edits - it seems very much like a list of lists isn't the right data structure for your logic here. A list is usually indicated when you can have arbitrarily many 'rows' in your table - it seems you always have exactly four. A tuple is better in this case - it is kindof like a list, except it is set up more deliberately for things that don't change. And, even better, since you want to address your four things by name, there's a standard Python class called [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) that makes this easy.

You would define a Table class like this:

```
Table = namedtuple('Table', ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right'])
```

And then you create your first table like this:

```
table = Table(up=["img1.png","img2.png"], down=..., left=..., right=...)
```

This lets you get your 'up' list as `table.up`, which means when you do a deepcopy into `table_r` per Constantinius' answer, *these names come with it for free*. And it also lets you iterate over it in exactly the same way as your list:

```
for i in range(len(table)):
    for j in range(len(table[i])):
       ...
```

However, note that iterating over `range(len(iterable))` is usually not necessary - since you're using the index to look up values from your two tables simultaneously, what you *really* want is a combination of the builtin functions `enumerate` and `zip`:

```
for row, row_r in zip(table, table_r):
    for i, (val, val_r) in enumerate(zip(row, row_r)):
       row[i] = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(str(val)))
       row_r[i] = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(str(val_r)))
```

You only need the index to assign into the lists, since rebinding `val` and `val_r` inside the inner loop won't work. Since you don't use `j` as anything other than a lookup, you don't need it at all.

But this also brings up the one caviat of using a namedtuple - the one thing it can't do that you might care about is change an attribute of the tuple after it is created:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> p = Point(1, 2)
>>> p.x = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    p.x = 2
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

In your case, this means you can't reassign `table.up` to a new list at any point (you can still change the list itself, though, through its mutation methods and slice assignment) - if you need that, you're best off coding your own class for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't have 4 rows, just simplified it for my question, but the same logic applies.
But that does mean that I am unable to horizontally flip my images after duplicating table into table_r (since you can't change the attribute)?

Comment: Actually, never mind that. I guess I simply must do the following:
`row_r[i] = pygame.transform.flip(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(str(val_r))),1,0)`

There's a slight problem tho. This: `table = Table(up=["img1.png","img2.png"], down=..., left=..., right=...)
` returns an invalid syntax error.

Comment: @GermainZ replace the '...' with the actual lists you want to initialise those to. And the transpose will work - anything your original code was doing with setting `row[j][i]` will still work - just anything that you would have spelled `row[j] = [...]` won't.

Comment: @Ivc I obviously did, not that newbish.
Here's the line that's giving me an invalid syntax:
(too long for comments) http://pastebin.com/1BBADiJe

I also tried without removing the box=, boxhigh=, etc... Same result.

Comment: @GermainZ you're missing a close paren on the line above it.

Comment: Thanks again... I'm seriously ashamed of the amount of questions I've already asked, and hope you're not too annoyed, but I have another problem:
`    for i, val, val_r in enumerate(zip(row, row_r)):
` returns the error: `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack`

Comment: @GermainZ that one's my fault - should be `for i, (val, val_r) in ...`- I'll fix it in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

I think, the `deepcopy` function suits fine in this occasion.

```
from copy import deepcopy

...
TABLE_1 = deepcopy(TABLE)
```

Comment: Damn you. Beat me to it by 11 seconds. +1

Comment: As I've said in my post, I'd like to rename the lists contained in the TABLE so that I can access them..

Comment: @GermainZ -- They weren't named to begin with since they were in a list.  If you want to name them, then you want to be using dictionaries, not lists.

Comment: Read edit #2... I just can't get the code to display as code in here.

Comment: @GermainZ new variables are trivial once you've got the copy of the big one, assuming you always know exactly how many there are - `table1_dup, table2_dup, table3_dup = TABLE_1`. But, as mgilson says, it sounds very much like you want a dictionary (or perhaps a `namedtuple`, but probably a dictionary) rather than a list here.

Comment: @lvc Sorry. As I've said, I'm new to Python (and to programming, in general). Could you please read my edit and confirm your answer? Meanwhile, I'll read about dictionaries.
Thanks

Comment: @GermainZ a dict of lists does seem indicated - that would let you do `table['up'] = [...]` etc, and simplify your code greatly. Also, note that `for i in range(len(table)):` isn't idiomatic Python - do `for row in table:` instead.

Comment: @GermainZ actually, on reflection, a namedtuple seems the way to go - see the answer I'm about to post for full details on how that would work.

Comment: I'm having some trouble with the dict of lists: here's what I'm trying to do:

`table_r={'box_r': list(box), 'boxhigh_r': list(boxhigh)}`

`for row in table_r:`

`table_r[j][i] = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(str(table_r[j][i])))`

But apparently dicts don't exactly have columns for my syntax to work. Is there a way to automate the process or must I adopt the manual approach (table_r['box_r'], table_r['boxhigh_r'] each on their own)?

EDIT: Posted this before your newest reply. Waiting for you answer, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
TABLE_1 = [ table[:] for table in TABLE ]
```

This only suits your purpose if the tables in TABLE do only contain immutables.

Comment: @JakobBowyer I wouldn't call it a shallow copy - that would be without the `[:]`, making it equivalent to `TABLE_1 = list(TABLE)`. But you do have point that its not really a deep copy since that implies a fully recursive copy. I'm not sure if there's standard terminology for it, but perhaps a one level deep copy?